# Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Isaac Newton?

Tags: museums, england, geek-travel, science

I'm travelling to the UK from Australia and wanted to visit a number of sites of scientific history.

One at the top of my list is Isaac Newton.

I can see you can visit his [home and do experiments](https://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/woolsthorpe-manor). Even do [a homestay](http://www.homestayengland.co.uk/4-day-homestay-packages/sir-isaac-newton-homestay/). And see [the Apple Tree](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/article-1386218/Isaac-Newtons-apple-tree-near-Grantham-Lincolnshire-fenced-off.html).

I can see you can go to where he was [Warden of the Mint](http://www.isaacnewton.org.uk/PlacesMap), and see items from [his estate](http://e%20Manager,%20The%20Estate%20Office,).

At Cambridge, Trinity College - [there appears to be](http://www.isaacnewton.org.uk/cambridge/) a room (by appointment), a statue, an Apple tree. It also appears to have the [Wren library](https://www.newton.ac.uk/about/isaac-newton) of his papers and personal effects.

He appears to have a [monument](https://www.newton.ac.uk/about/isaac-newton) at Westminster Abbey.

But can you visit a museum with a display about his life and works?

My question is: Are there any museums or sites in England honouring Isaac Newton?

Comment: I did post grad work at the Isaac Newton Institute in Cambridge and *loved* the white boards in the toilets. Check it out, you might overhear a Nobel Prize aspirant explaining a new theory!

Comment: There's a statue of Newton in the courtyard of the British Library in Euston Road

Comment: @GayotFow The Newton Institute isn't open to the public and its only link to Newton is that it was named after him. Also, there is no Nobel Prize in mathematics.

Comment: @DavidRicherby https://www.newton.ac.uk/about/history/nobel-physics

Comment: See also http://trinitycollegechapel.com/about/thebuilding/chapel-short-guide/

Comment: A clarification: the Wren library is not dedicated to Newton. It includes some of his manuscripts, but the majority of its contents are not related to Newton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there isn't such a museum in the entire United Kingdom. Wikipedia has an extremely comprehensive list of [museums in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_museums_in_the_United_Kingdom), but none of them include a place dedicated to Newton.

Comment: I'm skeptical that you can really know that none of these have a Newton display or similar. In fact, I'd anticipate some do.

Comment: @CMaster there's no museum dedicated to Newton but hundreds of them can have a Newton exhibit at some point

Answer (score 2):

The Tower of London has a section on the Royal Mint, which includes a small piece on Isaac Newton. The tower is definitely worth a visit if you are interested in political and military history. However, there is not too much scientific history there.